# Relationship between x,y,z,t to be $|a \cdot x + b \cdot y| < |a \cdot z + b \cdot t |$

Tags: analysis

Let $a,b,x,y,z,t \in \mathbb{C}$

What is the relationship between $x,y,z,t$ to be true that 
$$
|a \cdot x + b \cdot y| < |a \cdot z + b \cdot t |
$$

thanks

Comment: Setting $b/a=c$,and factorizing $|a|$, you have the equivalent condition $|  x + c \cdot y| < | z + c \cdot t |$, but it is still a very general constraint... I don't think much can be said...

Comment: thanks @JeanMarie  actually i think there's no more other to add